# Execute commands with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I tried to run commands with ssh login.

The `ls` command works fine,

```
ubuntu@arm64:~$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /root/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa ubuntu@192.168.50.2  ls
```

giving list of files/dir

But when I run `/bin/bash` with ssh it hanged (no response output).

```
ubuntu@arm64:~$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /root/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa ubuntu@192.168.50.2  /bin/bash
```

When I ran `/bin/bash` on 192.168.50.2 there is no output, but command returns. In case ssh command does not return from ssh, what is the reason?

Comment: You're starting an interactive shell, it doesn't hang, it's waiting for you to give it some input.

Comment: Thanks alot arco. i understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `/bin/bash` you are forking a new `bash` process, something like when you start up your terminal.

Just like with the terminal bash, bash over ssh is going to wait for you to give it further instructions before it returns any output to you.